# Is there a way to open windows explorer from IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

In the developpement sever everything is working perfectly but when deployed on IIS 7.5 the windows explorer is not displayed 
I'm using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", argument);
is there another way to do that?
P.S: I tried all the proposed solution to run System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", argument); but I didn't succeed
thanks

Comment: Are you trying to open explorer on the client? If so, you'll need to hyperlink to `file://C:/Windows/Explorer.exe` but it's bad practice. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes I want to open the explorer in the client side, my application display items and each item has his related folders in a shared driver, so I to give to the user the ability to click on a link and it will open directly the folder containg files of the item

Comment: I tried the hyperlink and it doesn't work too

Comment: I also tried to display System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; and it show the user with admin rights !!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You're code is running server side and you only have access to the server side process (if you have sufficient permissions, which normally shouldn't be the case).

You cannot open the client-side explorer, because you don't have access to the client's filesystem. You could include a link to `file://C:/Windows/Explorer.exe` as mentioned in the comments, but this will only work if the client really has windows installed on the C-drive and the windows-folder is named like that.

All in all, this is not a supported scenario.